# Changing the value of char Array in C

Tags: c, string

I have the following code:

```
 char b[20] = ("      string         ");        // Initialize the array
 for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)                    // Count i from 0 to 20
 {    
     set_outputs(26,19, (b[i]));                //Send LINE 
 }
```

My question is how can I replace `string` with a variable, so that I could say something like `string = windmill?`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
sprintf( b, "    %s    ", variable );
```

You will have to watch that you don't overrun your buffer.

Comment: I think so. That's why I posted it. Just make the buffer big enough to hold everything.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it, and let you know.